# How can I make a resize handle extend the entire vertical axis of an element in HTML/CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a basic side navbar with a width of around 300 px. I would like to make it horizontally resizable whenever the right-hand edge is clicked & dragged.

I see there is the CSS option for `resize: horizontal;`, but this creates the resizing handle only in the bottom right, and I am unable to find a way to make it a full vertical handle (i.e. extend the full vertical axis) using this property. Maybe this is the wrong approach then.

An alternative that I saw was to create an empty div that spans the entire vertical axis, and then attach/remove event handlers on mouse down/up/move events. Looks promising, but it seems quite involved. Before I go down that route, I would like to know what is the typical approach for doing this? Is there something in CSS that I am missing?

Comment: You could try using a library like [interact.js](https://interactjs.io/docs/resizable/). Otherwise, there isn't really a straightforward approach. You would have to go down the route you already mentioned.